Excel Search any item in a column in the current row (reverse search)
Hello I have data in such a format
Date | Usage | Value

I search in this (long) table using sumif
and sum the up in a new table
Category | Keyword| Sum
using:
=SUMMEWENN(INDIREKT("Data[" & [@[Suche in]]  &"]");"*"& [@Keyword] & "*";Data[Value])

This is the forward search, now I want to search backward, to see which Keyword are found and which are still missing.
Basically I want to to search in Data[Usage] every [Keyword] (whole column) and get to know if any can be found. However I could not find a proper solution in Excel.

Pardon me if I've misunderstood the question, is this what you're looking for:

this may not be most efficient way, but may be sufficient for your need

add column to the data table, for example, Has Keyword (please let me if it is not possible, I'll give an alternative)

SEARCH is not case sensitive, replace with FIND if needed

enter in first cell of Has Keyword


=SUM(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Keyword[Keyword], @[Usage]))) > 0

possible German translation
=SUMME(--ISTZAHL(SUCHEN(Keyword[Keyword]; @[Usage]))) > 0




It seems to work. What is the background of the double - sign?

It is a commonly used pattern to convert TRUE/FALSE values to 1/0 for calculations. It is not needed when used in expressions with other numerical operator (+,* etc.) Please let me know if you see any issues.
